# localstack sqs subscribe to sns doesn't work

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, localstack

I've recently tried to subscribe an sqs to sns on the localstack environment.
after creating sns and sqs I can not subscribe using sqs protocol if I provide the protocol attribute either on AWS CLI or AWS SDK like below:

using awslocal:

```bash
awslocal sns subscribe \
--notification-endpoint "http://localhost:4566/000000000000/test" \
--topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:test" \
```

using AWS SDK:

```
  const input: SubscribeCommandInput = {
    // SubscribeInput
    TopicArn: testTopicArn.TopicArn,
    Protocol: 'sqs',
    Endpoint: testQueueURL,
    ReturnSubscriptionArn: true,
  };
```

either way, I will end up with an error like the one below:

```
n error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Subscribe operation: Invalid parameter: SQS endpoint ARN
```

if I change the protocol to `http` it gets subscribed successfully, but the problem is that no messages end up in the queue after this type of subscription.
the local stack docker log is as follows:

```
 Received error on sending SNS message, putting to DLQ (if configured): 404 Client Error:  for url: http://localhost:4566/000000000000/test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper endpoint for an SQS queue destination of an SNS topic is the Queue ARN, not its URL. See the documentation here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html

> For the sqs protocol, the endpoint is the ARN of an Amazon SQS queue.

You'll need to get the SQS Queue ARN before subscribing to the topic, with for example:

`awslocal sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url http://{queueURL} --attribute-names QueueArn`

You can then pass this ARN to the `Endpoint` parameter to subscribe to the Topic.

Comment: I'm dealing with localstack. queues don't have any ARN in localstack.

Comment: Thanks @bentsku, I could manage to run it by getting the queue ARN from localstack. for those who will face the same Issue. they need to retrieve the queue arn using : `awslocal sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url http://localhost:4566/000000000000/test` first, then you should use this arn inside notification endpoint of your subscription.